# Can I turn off read access to field history for some users?

Tags: permissions, history-tracking, field-history

All users should be able to see Cases, generally.

Some of my users should see CaseHistory on the Case layout, and some (same profile) shouldn't.  Is there any way to remove View permissions on CaseHistory for that first group of users?

To be clear, I would like to assign View CaseHistory permissions to one group of users, and forbid another group from seeing it.

How would I do that in Salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

Note that users won't see field changes in the Case History related list for fields that they don't have at least read FLS access to.

That said, there's no way to do this completely. The best you can do is put the no-Case History folks in a different profile that has a different Page Layout that doesn't have the Case History related list. If they have the ability to create and run their own reports, though, they could still access the data. Which, if they have read on the Cases, they could have observed at different points in time anyway.

Comment: What if they don't have record-level access to the User who makes the change?

Comment: Like CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy, they'll see the user's name, but no details will be available.